# Should I host my academic website under my institution domain or under a domain of my own ?

Tags: website

My institution provides a dedicated storage space to host our academic websites, which is reachable via the institution domain (something like `http://people.institution.org/John.Doe/`).

I try to have a tidy website of a few pages listing my publications, research area, contact, etc. It is currently reachable through my institution domain. I try to also put some efforts in SEO when people look up for my name or particular research area on search engines.

I'm in my last year of Ph.D. and I will undoubtedly move to other institutions in the next few years, so I am wondering if it wouldn't be preferable to host my academic webpage on a dedicated domain `http://www.johndoe.com`, which would prevent the need to do the SEO all over again each time I will switch to a new institution.

The only advantage to use my institution domain is the affiliation, but this information is present on my website anyway.

I'm a Ph.D. student in electrical engineering in France, if it matters.

Comment: My experience has been that your university webpage will receive more traffic and more notability through search engine otherwise. Based on some of my work put on my page, I am the top result for at least one keyword which has resulted in being asked to review papers! I doubt this would have happened if I hosted it on my own.

Comment: Why would it receive more traffic ? There is no academic website list on my university site, apart from our research group page (in which I can modify the link to my website). As I said I was able to bring my website to the first page of results for selected keywords so I guess that shouldn't be different on my own domain.

Comment: Well, .edu domains are considered well in terms of Google's algorithms. You can also always mirror or redirect traffic from an .edu url. That might be the best thing if you already get traffic. My uni gave actually hosting space as in, .edu/~name

Comment: *.edu* TLDs are only used in the US so it's not relevant in my case (my institution uses a generic *.fr* TLD), but your remark is indeed of interest for people in US universities.

Comment: Actually a lot of the supposed "extra value" attributed to .edu domains is based on myth; if you do some searching you'll find that for the most part there is no significant benefit.

Comment: Some institutions don't even provide webpage set-up or space thus it would be wise to keep your own site. That said, you save about $50 a year by using the university site. I would use it if my university provided space.

Comment: @strnk Actually, `.edu` isn't *exclusively* used by US institutions: Universitat Politècnica de Catalunya in Barcelona uses `upc.edu`. But, anyway, non-US `.edu` domains are very much in the minority and, as you say, your institution isn't one of them.

Comment: Besides redirecting your own webpage as nayrb mentions, if your institution is amenable, they can set up url forwarding to automatically forward to your current url (as well as with email), even long after your uni accounts expire.

Comment: @Kimball : it's possible, yes (see [Raphael's answer](http://academia.stackexchange.com/a/26187/6817) ), but it doesn't apply in my case unfortunately.

Comment: @strnk: Ah, I didn't read that far down on the answers.  That's too bad.  My postdoc department did that for me, and I figured many universities would be willing to do so for people at the post-bac level, as it only requires a miniscule amount of resources.

Comment: How popular is your website?  How many links are there to it in the wild?  Is your institution going to agree on maintaining a redirect at that address for a couple of years?  If it's primarily a professional website about *you*, then I agree with Ben's advice.  But if your website has a lot of generally useful content and many links to it, changing address is going to be a very significant problem when you change institutions.  At least if your IT dept. won't agree to a long term redirect.

Comment: I used to think the same way as Ben but now I regret not getting my own domain because of all the broken links that moving is going to cause ... if your current institution agreed to a redirect, that's great.  But your next one might not agree (my situation).

Comment: _if you do some searching you'll find that for the most part there is no significant benefit_ — [citation needed]

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Why don't you just do both? By both, I mean use both URLs. I "do both", so when I graduate, I'll still have my site for others to see. You can do this in many ways, but I had my university student page auto-redirect to my personal home page. The code for that is like a one-liner.

This grants me the opportunity to refer people to different sites depending on the situation. I think myname.com is undoubtedly easier to remember than the nuances in my university student site URL: people.school.org/first.last ... On the other hand, if the situation is more institution-based, perhaps it's better to stick with my college's name. You've got options this way.

Comment: Having a redirect really isn't the same as having both. I have my own site and of course my department links to that on my faculty profile and the standard .edu/~name is a redirect link. But I don't think that would be considered "both" as my info is only on one site.

Comment: Related suggestion: if you are going to have both, use [canonical links](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.it/2009/02/specify-your-canonical.html).

Comment: Both are good points for sure. TBH I should revise the answer a bit. I was not really considering the faculty case because of my (perhaps invalid) interpretation on OPs mention of leaving the current school though. Plus a department faculty page requires almost no effort to maintain at my school; faculty/postdocs email research/publication updates to the webmaster who changes their dpt. page. Lab group/personal site obviously a different story!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think I will mainly host my website on a domain of my own, and making a redirection from my university page to my domain.

Answer (score 39):

I find it really strange that no one has mentioned the possible reputational benefits of using the university's website.   I don't think there's any way to write this without sounding like a snob, but I'll say it anyways; people are snobbier than they like to admit, and academia is probably worse than many other fields.  If you're at an at all prestigious institution (even actually, if you're at a not so prestigious one), you want to emphasize that affiliation.  Of course, your work has to stand on its own two feet ultimately, but people will be more open to it if they see you're connected to a serious institution, rather than some dude in his basement (remember, there's always something they could be doing rather than reading your paper).  Most academics keep a mental rolodex of where people are located for different purposes, like knowing where to send students or where they might like to visit.  Why make it harder for them to figure this out?

A couple of other commenters have mentioned that you should be building your own brand, not the universities, but I don't see how you separate those.  Usually, the university has a much stronger brand than you do, so you want to steal a bit of it for yourself.  If you're in a situation where this isn't the case, it's still a virtuous cycle where improving the department's reputation should ultimately pay you back, and shouldn't stop you from moving.

That said, I've certainly experienced the trouble of moving my website (many times), so I see the appeal of having a stable website that doesn't have to be moved, but why not both?

Comment: +1, this is the only answer so far that bears even a remote semblance to my experiences in academia. (Well, except @RoboKaren's remark about content management systems. That one's spot on.) The implied view in some of the other answers of treating your current employer as your antagonist in your academic career is frankly bizarre.

Comment: +1, you are discussing the untold importance of our affiliation, I was expecting someone to talk about it. I'd love to see other people view on that. As per "why not both": it would be a burden to maintain two separate websites. If they just have the same content then it's not even useful to keep them both... I'd rather go for @rch answer for that purpose: redirecting my university page to my own domain.

Comment: @strnk: FWIW, the redirection also works the other way around, always, with no hassle at all (in terms of setting it up and potential conflict with your institution's interests).

Answer (score 18):

Reasons to use your own host/tld:

1. You don't expect to be at your current (or future) institution for very long.
2. Your institution uses a painful CMS system, requires you to use ugly templates, or has content or size restrictions.
3. You don't want to ask your department head or IT manager/webmistress for permission every time you want to update your page.
4. Your personal brand is more important than the university brand (see #1).
5. You are part of a multi-university project.
6. You created your own domain website when you were a graduate student and never found a good reason to switch to your employers' sites, even a dozen plus years after graduation (my case).
7. etc.

Reasons to only use your university website:

1. It's the default position.
2. It doesn't cost you any additional hosting or domain registration fees.
3. In many cases, the department or IT admin will help you set it up using one of their templates, meaning you do not have to learn web design
4. In some cases, the database that populates your research publications will be pulled from your Faculty Annual Report (or vice
   versa). This means that keeping the university CMS happy results in
   less paperwork overall in terms of reporting your research
   activities to the university.
5. The google-juice (SEO) of the university will likely be higher than your own.
6. Some may argue it looks more professional to have an .edu/~name site rather than a private.com website.
7. Loyalty
8. etc.

And of course, one can always do both. The cons of doing both are:

1. Requires updating both.
2. Visitors may be confused about which site to go to (or you have the same info mirrored, which leads to #1)

Comment: Keeping your website on your university is the default position so I didn't think it required explanation.  I'll edit to add.

Comment: I'd like to suggest 3b. for the reasons to only use one's university site: Sometimes, these include a central (for the department, or even larger organisational units) database of publications and templates that automatically show a filtered view of each website owner's publications are available and maintained already. Even when that central database is not updated "centrally" (such as a secretary always entering all new publications made by someone from the department), it means at least that only one of the co-authors of each publication has to input the publication data.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper - done. The A.SE CMS engine doesn't allow for nested lists so I added your reason as reason #4 in the use-the-university list.

Comment: @RoboKaren: OT: Actually, it does: It seems than you just need to indent the nested list items by at least one more space than the parent level.

Comment: If I double indent, it'd list it as 3* or 3+, not 3b. As far as I can tell, one can't do <ol style=lower-roman> style a. b. c. d. ordered lists in A.SE. If it's possible, let me know!

Answer (score 6):

I think you should do both, but in a different way that has been [suggested by Raphael](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/26187/5962) and [by rch](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/26141/5962). Both of these other suggestions involve doing some sort of invisible "redirect" from one page (almost always the temporary institutional page) to the permanent page on your domain. [RoboKaren suggested having two pages](https://academia.stackexchange.com/a/26140/5962) which is the closest to my answer. I suggest you should create a page on your institution but have it be a small "soft" redirect that asks people to click through.

Keep an institutional page but keep it very simple. Have the page give the following information (at most):

- A short narrative biography of you and your research or teaching interests.
- A nice recent picture of you. [Nice, but optional.]
- A link to your CV on your website. [Optional]
- A list of 2-3 recent selected papers. [Optional]
- **A very prominent link to your actual homepage on your domain**. I do this with text like, "For more detail on my research and teaching, visit full academic homepage.

Ben Webster is correct in [citing the importance of association with your institution for status reasons](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/26130/should-i-host-my-academic-website-under-my-institution-domain-or-under-a-domain) In order to get the benefit, put the name and the logo and/or seal for your institution prominently on your personal page in a way that makes it clear that you are associated with the institution but also clear that it is your personal page.

This is what I have been doing for years. One benefit is that many institutions make updating institutional pages tricky (e.g., you need to go through a webmaster). This is a nice compromise in this situation because you only need to update the biography, picture, etc. infrequently.

Comment: I wonder why you propose putting teaching material on the privately-hosted site. Arguably, this material that a) *belongs* on the institution site and b) never has to move with you. More so, it should probably stay even if you leave.

Comment: @Raphael, you are right. I put material that is specific to a instance of a specific course (i.e., COM597B in Spring 2014) in the course management website run by my institution. I put general resources or curriculum I have developed (curriclum for a course on innovation and online communities) and that I have used and will use at any institution on my personal website. I agree that my curriclum should stay available to students at my old institution. That said, few institutions will promise to keep websites up after you leave.

Comment: I see, that makes sense. (The point "they'll take it down, anyway" keeps coming up and I don't think I like that situation; researchers' websites are sometimes the only place to get preprints and other information. My department still hosts websites of professors that have been gone for 13 years. Even students keep their email accounts.)

Comment: @Raphael, the preprint stuff is a big issue. If it's allowed, it's always a good idea to put preprints in an institutional archive (usually run by the libraries) in addition to a personal website. No website is permanent.

Comment: _belongs on the institution site and never has to move with you_ — Both of these assumptions are incorrect.  At my university, copyright to instructional materials belongs to their creators (but they must give the university a permanent royalty-free licence). And if you plan to continue teaching after you graduate, _of course_ you want to maintain your own teaching materials.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to find a design solution for a technical problem that does not exist.

You mention SEO as your primary concern (for whatever reason¹). So when you move your professional website to another institution, (have your admin) put a [301 (Moved Permanently)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_301) in your old website's `.htaccess` and search engines will automatically update their databases accordingly.

This assumes that you can keep your old (sub)domain/page at least for a few months; as far as I can tell, this is common. Many groups/departments maintain lists to alumni at their current position, anyway; it is as much advertisement for them as it is for you (if you're good).

Note that you can still use one domain as an alias for the other. Which direction you choose is probably irrelevant in most cases. I'd argue that it *is* important to have *something* at an institution URL so that you have a representative address that looks official and leaves no doubt that you are, indeed, *the* John Doe from the University of Illustriousness and not some dude who happend to be the first to register john-doe.com.

---

1. As a researcher, I figure that your publications are your business cards. These are indexed in other places and your moving does not change how they can be found (and thank the powers that be for that!). Search engines pick up on your new website in a matter of days (for some you can even trigger indexing yourself) which should be enough, assuming that there is little more value but contact data besides the publications there. But ymmv.

Comment: Occasionally, one finds an institution, such as a previous employer of mine, which claims that it is technically impossible even to forward email to somebody who has left!

Comment: @DavidRicherby That's a bummer. I guess there is no upper bound on incompetence after all. That said, I would assume that group/department websites are often under more accommodating care (advisor/department staff) than email services (central technical division), so website forwarding/linking may actually work out better than email in such cases.

Comment: While I agree with your point on redirection my employer doesn't provide any way for me to do that after the end of my contract. No 301 redirection on my *old* web site nor even e-mail redirection.

Comment: @strnk Hm. Can you set up the 301 *before* you leave, pointing towards a place you control (and put a temporary clone of your site)? A couple of days, weeks at most are enough for Google et al to process it.

Comment: If I have a "place [I] control" then I would rather use it as my main server and put 301 redirections to there since it's more *permanent*. That would avoid the hassle of having to copy my website back and forth and possibly adapt it to a server config each time I move to a new place.